# Objective-C- Getting the object with the greatest property value

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a Car class. It's got a property called enginePower. On the other hand I have an NSArray that contains more than 50 car objects. How would I select the car with the highest enginePower which at the same time is less than the given value. To be more clear:

```
BMW X5-345 hp
Audi A3-200 hp
BMW 525i -225 hp
VW Passat CC-175 hp
.....
```

Now, from this array of cars when I ask for the car with the highest enginePower which is less than 320 it should give me BMW 525i. Is it possible to achieve. I mean is there a nice and easy way or does it need lots of lines of code?

Comment: Look at [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=nspredicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided by @Jasarien would work just fine, but if you want to avoid writing the code to loop through you might try something like:

```
- (Car *)getHighestPowerFromCars:(NSArray *)carArray atLeast:(NSNumber *)minPower {
    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"enginePower" ascending:NO]];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [carArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"enginePower >= %@", minPower];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array using the engine power property, then loop through the array until you find an `enginePower` value that is greater than the one specified. Then take the value of the object in `currentArrayIndex - 1`.

You can do this by using `-compareUsingSelector:` on an `NSMutableArray` or `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` on an `NSArray` (which will return a new, sorted, autoreleased array).

You can create a method on your `Car` class named something like `-compareUsingEnginePower:` which will take another `Car` object as the parameter.

Then you can compare the two `enginePower` properties and return one of `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending`.

Comment: That seems like it will sort all the cars in power order, but the OP wants to select a car from the subset of cars which have power less than a nominal value.

Answer (score -1):

Straightforward iteration through the array, looking only at cars below the power limit, and picking the one with the highest power:

```
— (Car *)getHighestPowerFromCars:(NSArray *)carArray lessThan:(NSNumber *)maxPower
{
    NSNumber* highest = nil;
    Car* highestCar = nil;

    for (Car* car in carArray)
    {
        NSNumber* power = car.enginePower;
        if ([power compare:maxPower] == NSOrderedAscending])
        {
            if (highest == nil || [power compare:highest] == NSOrderedDescending])
            {
                highest = power;
                highestCar = car;
            }
        }
    }

    return highestCar;
}
```

But there isn't any reason really why enginePower should be an NSNumber and not for example a double. Assuming that the power is never negative:

```
— (Car *)getHighestPowerFromCars:(NSArray *)carArray lessThan:(double)maxPower
{
    double highestPower = -1.0;
    Car* highestCar = nil;

    for (Car* car in carArray)
    {
        double power = car.enginePower;

        if (power < maxPower && power > highestPower))
        {
            highestPower = power;
            highestCar = car;
        }
    }

    return highestCar;
}
```

But then sorting and predicates are soooo fast...

Comment: I would call using the offered tools «Straightforward», not micro and premature optimization.